# How to access html data in python flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have html file which contain the different information.Example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>welcome</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to access the welcome in python file which is in the flask server.How we can access that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the package [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>welcome</h1>
</body>
</html> """

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
print(soup.h1.text)
# 'welcome'
```